# How t optimize read time in a postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a slight problem with a postgresql database with exploding read times.

Background info:

two tables, both with only 4 columns: uuid (uuid), timestamp (bigint), type (text) and value (double) in one, values (double[]) in the other. (yes, I thought about combining it in one table... decision on that isn't in my hands).

Given that only a fairly small amount of the held data is needed for each "projectrun", I'm already copying the needed data to tables dedicated to each projectrun. Now the interesting part starts, when I try to read the data:

```
CREATE TABLE fake_timeseries1
(
    "timestamp" bigint,
    uuid uuid,
    value double precision,
    type text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE fake_timeseries1
    OWNER to user;

CREATE INDEX fake_timeseries1_timestamp_idx
    ON fake_timeseries1 USING btree
    (timestamp)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE fake_timeseries1
    CLUSTER ON fake_timeseries1_timestamp_idx;
```

From that temporary table I do:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? ;"
```

Simple enough, should work rather fast, right? Wrong.

At the moment I'm testing with small batches (only x*40k rows, returning 25% of them).

For 10k rows, it takes "only" 6 sec, 20k already 34 sec, and for 40k rows (out of a mere 160k) it already takes 3 minutes per table ... 6 minutes for a mere 6 Mb of data. (yes, we are at a gb line, so it's probably no bottleneck there)

I already tried using an index and cluster on timestamp, but that does slow it down even more. Interestingly not on the creation of the temporary tables, but rather when reading the data.

What could I do to speed up the read process? It needs to be able to read those 10-50k rows in less than 5 minutes (preferably less than 1 minute) from a table that holds not 160k rows, but rather tens of millions.

What could be responsible for a simple Select being as slow as creating the whole table in the first place? (3 mins read vs. 3.5 mins create).

Thank you in advance.

As wished an analyze (for 20k out of 80k):

```
"Execution Time": 27.501,
"Planning Time": 0.514,
"Plan": {
  "Filter": "((\"timestamp\" >= '1483224970970'::bigint) AND (\"timestamp\" <= '1483232170970'::bigint))",
  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
  "Relation Name": "fake_timeseries1",
  "Alias": "fake_timeseries1",
  "Actual Rows": 79552,
  "Rows Removed by Filter": 0,
  "Actual Loops": 1
},
"Triggers": []
```

The real execution time was 34.047 seconds.

UPDATE:

continued testing with different test data sets. The following is an analyze from a significantly larger testset, where I read only 0.25% of the data... still using seq scan. Anyone an idea?

```
[
  {
    "Execution Time": 7121.59,
    "Planning Time": 0.124,
    "Plan": {
      "Filter": "((\"timestamp\" >= '1483224200000'::bigint) AND (\"timestamp\" <= '1483233200000'::bigint))",
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Relation Name": "fake_forecast",
      "Alias": "fake_forecast",
      "Actual Rows": 171859,
      "Rows Removed by Filter": 67490381,
      "Actual Loops": 1
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

UPDATE: After even more testing, on a second PostgresQL Database, it seems that I somehow have hit a hard cap.

Whatever I do, the max I can get is 3.3k rows from those two tables per second. And that's only if I use the sweet spot of calling for 20-80k rows in a large batch. Which take 6 resp. 24 seconds even on a DB on my own machine.

Is there nothing that can be done (except better hardware) to speed this up?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ? 6MB in 6 minutes, sounds like a big problem.

Comment: Maybe this one at dba.se helps http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/33821

Comment: You are including network transmission time. The database execution time is just 27 miliseconds.

Comment: If the timestamp range returns more than a few percent of the table then a sequential scan will be done regardless of the existing indices.

Comment: But network transmission time can't go up by a factor of 6 for each doubling of size. Basically each 10k row batch is 1 Mb. 10k: 6 sec, 20k, 34 sec, 40k 176 sec... Something is really fishy. :/